# Is there a way to speed up this triple loop?

Tags: r, performance, loops, vectorization

I am having a hard time speeding up this function (which becomes crucial for me when sample size is 10,000). Would any good soul help me on that?

I am making a toy, fully reproducible code below:

```
omega_w <- function(X){
  X <- as.matrix(X)
  n <- dim(X)[1]
  kdim <- dim(X)[2]
  omega <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n) # n x n

  for (j in 1:n){
    for (l in 1:j){
      for (r in 1:n){
        x.jr <- ((X[j,])-(X[r,]))
        x.lr <- ((X[l,])-(X[r,]))
        if (l==r && j==r){
          omega[j,l] <- omega[j,l] + 2*pi }
        else if ((l==r || j==r) && j!=l){
          omega[j,l] <- omega[j,l] + pi }
        else if (l==j && j!=r){
          omega[j,l] <- omega[j,l] + pi } 
        else {
          omega[j,l] <- omega[j,l] + abs(pi - acos(cor(x.jr,x.lr)))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  omega <- (omega + t(as.matrix(Matrix::tril(omega,-1)))) * pi^(kdim/2-1)/gamma(kdim/2 +1)
  return(omega)
} 

x <- as.matrix(rnorm(10000*20),10000,20)
w <- omega_w(x)
```

I would really appreciate any guidance on to make this function "better" and more computationally efficient. I am not really that worried about large matrices, as I will use this with sample sizes approximately the same as the one in the example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question should be asked on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as you seek optimization of working code. Also do explain in words what you are attempting to calculate.

Comment: The inner loop can be remove by using nested `ifelse` statements or `dplyr::case_when`